# installation path for visual studio 2008 addin in XP

Tags: visual-studio-addins

I tried to google for the installation path for visual studio 2008 addin in XP but could not find a proper answer.
Can someone help me on this
the addin needs to be for all users for the machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, I was able to find this out using the VS2008 IDE

tools->options->Environment->Add in /Macros Security tab

Answer (score 0):

C:\Documents and Settings\alexs.DOMAIN\Application Data\Microsoft\MSEnvShared\Addins